# How to escape table name in @Formula

Tags: hibernate

I have `Group` entity which contains formula for subselecting user count for each group:

```java
@Table(name = "\"group\"")
public class Group {
    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user` u, user_group ug WHERE u.deleted = 0 AND u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = id)")
    int userCount;

    ...
}
```

When I escape the `user` table name in the formula definition then the result query is:

```sql
SELECT
    group0_.id AS id1_2_, group0_.name AS name2_2_, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group0_."user" u, group0_.user_group group0_.ug 
     WHERE u.deleted = 0 AND u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = group0_.id) AS formula1_ 
FROM 
    "group" group0_
```

In that case `group` table alias `group0_.` is added before `"user"` but that is nonsense and logically does not work.

When I do not escape the `user` table name in the formula definition then the DB logically complains about not existing table because `user` is a keyword.

Is it possible to escape table name in a `@Formula`? Or can I somehow force Hibernate to don't add main table alias there?

**Note**: I cannot change table names so renaming them is not the solution!

Hibernate version is *5.4.21.Final*, dialect is `org.hibernate.dialect.ProgressDialect` for production and `org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` for intergation tests.

Comment: What hibernate version and dialect do you use?

Comment: Not sure if you are allowed to do but you can create a view over table and you can write formula over view instead of table